# Named pipe task

Tags: c, pipe, named-pipes

I have to creat a program which read two numbers from txt and find the LCM then write the numbers into another txt.

I have to use named pipe while reading from input.txt

Input txt:

- n (nunber of rows)
- x y

Output txt:

- x y z (z = LCM(x,y))

I guess I need to creat a fifo file, then read from input.txt and write the numbers into fifo. Then read out the numbers from it, do LCM then write it to output file.
How can i make it? I made this program without pipe.

```
int main()
{
    int n, x, y, z;
    FILE* fbe;
    FILE* fki;
    if((fbe = fopen("be.txt", "r")) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fki = fopen("ki.txt", "w");
    fscanf(fbe, "%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fbe, "%d %d", &x, &y);
        z = lnko(x, y);
        fprintf(fki, "%d %d %d\n", x, y, z); 
    }
    fclose(fbe);
    fclose(fki);
    return 0;
}

int lnko(int x, int y)
{
    int temp;
    while(y > 0)
    {
        temp = y;
        y = x%y;
        x = temp;
    }
    return x;
}
```